# symlink at sites/all/modules/civicrm doesn't work

Tags: developer

I am used to put all my development stuff (not only civicrm) at a certain point on my linux machine, therefore I use symlink from

```
<drupal base>/sites/all/module/civicrm to /my/devel/path/civicrm
```

This has the benefit of pointing the link to a newer version of civicrm as a means of upgrade or testing new developments.

This doesn't work when I change the symlink to point to another version of my development.
The instructions regarding upgrade civicrm (for example to 4.6) won't be helpful here because they talk about replacing the files locally.

Do you think the way I work is not logical?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure there is only one symlink (name does not matter) from modules directory to any civicrm directory outside web root. You might also need to restart apache after you delete the additional symlinks / directory

Answer (score 2):

It's how I do it, it works fine.

So you have (outside of the drupal folder) several folders civicrm-4.5.4 civicrm-4.6.2 ...

and (within the sites/all/modules create a single symlink civicrm -> the later civicrm-4.6.2)

The name doesn't matter, but as you will have urls that use it, I recommend keeping civicrm as the name of the symlink, and only keep a single one that you symlink with the civicrm version you want

then you upgrade normally using civicrm/upgrade and voila

Comment: didn't work for me

Comment: could you clarify what didn't work?

Comment: @DonaldLobo what you wrote, together with restarting apache service has solved. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Symlinks may have to be enabled in the Apache configuration by putting
    Options FollowSymLinks
in your .htaccess or apache config file.